# How can React show data as soon as backend gets data from MQ

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I am using Spring Boot as backend.

And I use @JmsListener to listen specific ActiveMQ.

My purpose is as soon as listener gets data from MQ, backend will send this data to
frontend(I use React) immediately, and shows data in GUI.

How can I achieve this requirement ?

Comment: There's lots of ways to skin a cat. Your question needs to be more specific. At this point your question is going to elicit more opinion-based answers than fact-based answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of websockets in order to make a real time communication between backend and frontend, so that the backend can send the produced information to the client (React App). Take a look in the [article here](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/socket-react/) to find an example of such case.

**Alernative**

The most common solution without websockets because of the added complexity would be that the React Frontend makes regular pings to backend for example with interval of 4-5 seconds until the backend is able to respond. While pinging the backend you can have the user wait with a spinner or such notification.

Comment: Why not just use the sockets instead of polling .